# HTML - Using same name for an ID and a Class

Tags: html, css

Is it O.K. to use the same name for a classname and an ID name? Is it a code smell?

```
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Why not run your page through the [**W3C Validator**](http://validator.w3.org/)?

Comment: @rednaw Sorry to be picky, but does that comment really add anything? There were already 3 answers with a total of 13 upvotes.

Comment: It is not a problem, but only `id` is sufficient for both CSS and accessing the DOM element using JavaScript.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Sorry man, just trying to put in some humor sometimes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's valid to do it. It's not common to *need* to do it, though: it's a bit of a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). It may indicate you need to revisit your naming conventions.

To expand on the issue of naming conventions and semantics:

When you use an ID of `wrapper`, you're saying "This is *the* wrapper - the only one of its kind". When you use a class of `wrapper` you're saying "This is *one of the* wrappers, and there may be others like it". Saying both of those things at the same time is a bit weird, right?

I'd suggest that you use a specific ID: `#primaryWrapper`, `#outerWrapper`, etc. That means you're expressing 'primaryWrapper is one of the wrappers', which makes heaps more sense.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes, it's totally valid and you can do it**

Hopefully you know that
`#ID` must be unique-per-page, while
`.CLASS` can be assignet to more than one element.

If you incline to write clean and readable `HTML` markup, try always to keep your attributes at an understandable minimum.

Comment: But don't use an `id` more than once. Additionally, you should realize that older versions of Internet Explorer are case insensitive.

Comment: He said that #ID "must be unique-per-page".

Answer (score 3):

Yes you could, but as a general rule you shouldn't. Classes can be reused, but IDs ned to remain unique. Try `wrapper1` an `wrapper2` if you need to.

Comment: I'd say that wrapper1 (as an ID) and wrapper2 (as a class) would be even less useful than wrapper as both ID and class: the 1 and 2 seem to indicate that the two are siblings/equals, which isn't the case.

Comment: I suppose in some instances one would confuse this...especially if they are using the same name for an id and a class...

Answer (score 3):

**Yes it is OK**, from the broswers' percpective they are two completely different elements.

The classes are defined using `.` and IDs are defined using `#`.

But be careful to not confuse yourself when coding.

For more info you can refer to the documentation of

**Element identifiers: the id and class attributes** at

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are different entities.  However, it is not OK to use the same ID on multiple entities.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you are OK.

As people stated, just remember that you keep the id unique.

POINTER:

classes are usually used to group many things that would be styled the same or very similarly.

id's are used to identify a specific element, mainly for javascript.

Comment: The distinction that classes are mainly used for styling and IDs for Javascript isn't true, and it's not even a reliable convention - some people might use them that way, but just as many don't. This question can be answered without reference to CSS or Javascript.